# Update a column based on counter from another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table the fields are `Id1`, `ID2`, `Points1`, `Points2`. I have another table that has the columns `Id1`, `Id2`, `Address1`, `address2`, `city 1`, `city2`, `state1`, `state2`. I have to update the `pointsA` and `PointsB` column based on how many of the columns in the second table are filled meaning they dont have null. Ex

Table 1

```
ID1  ID2   Points 1 Points2
1     2     2         0
```

Table 2

```
ID1  ID2 Address1 address2 city 1 city2 state1 state2.
1    2    a1       null     null   null  s1     null
```

How can I achieve this in sql server 2008?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE t1
SET 
    Points1 = t2.Points1, 
    Points2 = t2.Points2
FROM
    Table1 t1 JOIN (
    SELECT
        ID1,
        ID2,
        CASE WHEN Address1 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END +
        CASE WHEN City1 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END +
        CASE WHEN State1 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS Points1,
        CASE WHEN Address2 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END +
        CASE WHEN City2 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END +
        CASE WHEN State2 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS Points2,
    FROM Table2
) t2 ON t1.ID1 = t2.ID1 AND t1.ID2 = t2.ID2
```